# Iam using android emulator but i can't access root, su is not working for root in adb shell

Tags: root-access, android-emulator, google-pixel-2

[image]

In this image i have given the screenshot of my command prompt,anyone know this please explain how access root in android emulator

Comment: By default, Android emulator is not rooted. You might be interested in [How to get root access on Android emulator? -- Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5095234/2821954)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, I can't actually tell which image your are trying to boot. You could actually try running Google APIs Intel images as opposed to Google Play images. As discussed in the linked question you could also utilise an older ramdisk.img.

Alternatively just [push the su binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473415), if you want wide-access root for any app you install on your emulator.